# How to use not like inside single quotes?

Tags: oracle

I am trying the below query to delete some attributes from xml.

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET column_name = DELETEXML(xmltype (FILE_NAME), '//path/value[@id not like "%.1"]').getClobVal()
```

I want to delete attributes which id value is not like '%.1'. But 'not like' method is present
inside the single quotes, so it is not considering not like as a method.

Someone help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'not like' is an sql function you need to use an xpath equivalent.

If you know there will only be one '.' in the string then something along the lines of the below should work.

`UPDATE table_name 
SET column_name = DELETEXML(xmltype (FILE_NAME), '//path/value[not(substring-after(@id, '.') = "1")]').getClobVal()`

if there could be more than one '.' then it is more complicated but something along the lines of the below should work.

`UPDATE table_name 
SET column_name = DELETEXML(xmltype (FILE_NAME), '//path/value[not(substring(@id, string-length(@id) - 2) = ".1")]').getClobVal()`